# Docker dpage/pgadmin4 error: specified user does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
############################
# Setup database container #
############################
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks:
      - db_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.19
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:8080/tcp
    environment: 
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - db_network

networks: 
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
```

There is a `.env` file in the same directory.

```
# The above refers to the name of the postgres container since using docker-compose
# This is because docker-compose creates a user-defined network. Kubernetes also does this.
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=website
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=website
POSTGRES_DB=wikifakes_main
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=info@my-website.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=my-secure-password
```

When executing `docker-compose up --build` both docker start and I can access the pgAdmin4 website via `localhost:8001`.
However, after entering the credentials, I get the following response:

> **Specified user does not exist**

Why does the specified user not exist and how should I change my environment so that I can log in?

The login on an `pgadmin4` docker created via `docker run --rm -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="info@my-website.com" -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="my-secure-password" -p 8001:80 dpage/pgadmin4` works alright though.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I keep my env variables in a .bashrc file. My problem was that I had $ symbol in my password and used double quotes for the variable declaration. Apparently, only single quotes escape $ correctly. After I changed " with ' - everything started to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `tty: true` to the `pgadmin` service in the docker-compose.yml file.

```yaml
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.19
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:8080/tcp
    environment: 
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - db_network
    # ADD THIS LINE
    tty: true
```

So the complete file will look as follows:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
############################
# Setup database container #
############################
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks:
      - db_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.19
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:8080/tcp
    environment: 
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - db_network
    # ADD THIS LINE, TO BE ABLE TO LOGIN
    tty: true

networks: 
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but still I get message "Specified user does not exist". I copied code above.

Comment: Do you have the .env file in the same folder as the docker compose file?

Comment: I verified once again and it works now. Maybe that was something wrong with configuration of my workstation. In short, it works!

Comment: This did not make any difference for me, but my username was not a valid email string and after changing that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Delete `/var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db` (it might be mounted to somewhere) or try to delete it inside the container and run it again.

Your problem is most likely because you ever start the container, then you change `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD`.

There is a code snippet when your container starts

```
if [ ! -f /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db ]; then
```

When the container starts **for the first time**, it will create a file named `/var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db`. `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD` will be stored inside `pgadmin4.db` (with the password being hashed).

So, when the container starts again, `pgadmin4.db` file has been created and will not go to the branch in the code snippet above so that `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD` change will not be updated.

---

Alternately, you can exec shell to the container

```
[user:host ~]$ docker exec -it <your container> sh
```

and inspect the email registered

```
[pgadmin:<container_id> /pgadmin4]$ cat /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db | egrep '\S+@\S+\.\S+'
```

Answer (score 1):

tty is NOT required but you need to mention dependencies (depends_on and links) !

```
version: '3.1'

services:
############################
# Setup database container #
############################
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks:
      - db_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.19
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:8080/tcp
    environment: 
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - db_network
    # ADD THIS LINE, TO BE ABLE TO LOGIN
    tty: true
    depends_on: # <-- !!!!!
      - postgres_db # <-- !!!!!
    links: # <-- !!!!!
      - postgres_db # <-- !!!!!
```

Comment: What if I don't need a postgres_db container. I Already have a running database. I just need pgAdmin one. I can run it, but cannot login to gui even though I pass the variables.