# pgAdmin Docker Error: 'Incorect username or password'

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

Have some simple docker-compose.yml file configuration, but I am not sure why I can't not login to pgAdmin using *pgadmin4@pgadmin.org* as email and *admin* as a password. Does it need more configuration or am I using wrong credentials?

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:13.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./init-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
        networks:
            - appNetwork

    pgAdmin:
        container_name: pgAdmin
        # restart: unless-stopped
        image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.29
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
            PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
        volumes:
            - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
        ports:
            - "5050:5050"
        depends_on:
            -   db
        networks:
            - appNetwork

volumes:
    db-data:
    pgadmin:

networks:
    appNetwork:
        driver: bridge
```

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue with `admin`/`admin` credentials, it seems the email needs to be an email string and not just any username. It worked with `admin@whatever.com`.

Comment: the docker pgadmin image is crap am sorry to day. seems i may have to create my own image. The error messages are the worst. Docker containers should not be rocket science like this

Answer (score 19):

You define `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD` and also use a persistent volume `pgadmin`. Maybe you previously created an instance with a different email/password which have been persisted in `pgadmin` volume and is not overriden by your newly defined variables.

You can try to delete stack containers and volumes with:

```
# WARNING: this will delete all containers and volumes
# including pg_data volume and pgadmin volume
# make sure to make a backup if needed
docker-compose down -v
```

Alternatively, you can just stop pgAdmin container and specifically delete the `pgadmin` volume:

```
docker-compose rm -s pgAdmin

# Replace project_name by your Docker Compose project name
# Use docker volume ls to show all volumes and choose the proper one
docker volume rm project_name_pgadmin
```

Then re-create `pgAdmin` container and volume (and if necessary other components):

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Thank you, used first solution. But sadly same result.

Comment: Do you have a .env in your local folder that may overrides these variables?

Comment: I have but they are the same.
Interesting to know that using this command I was able to login 

```docker run -p 5050:80 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test1234" -d  dpage/pgadmin4:4.29```

But not using .yml configurations

Comment: ```https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020606/2956929```

used this link, I am still not sure why it is working now, or why is was not working before

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I am using mac m1 machine and this script was the missing jigsaw piece I was looking for.

Comment: yes! the docker-compose down -v  did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was not working for any of the below users:

```
‘PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@domain.local’
'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.local'
```

Then I used a different one:

```
'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@admin.org'
```

And it worked. Not sure what's the reason may be the other two are too common.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Take my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already used the service **pgAdmin** and it related container: **container_name: pgAdmin**

The solution would be to give them other names as follow:

```
pgAdminNew:
    container_name: pgAdmin_new
    # restart: unless-stopped
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.29
    environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
        PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    volumes:
        - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
        - "5050:5050"
    depends_on:
        -   db
    networks:
        - appNetwork
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by deleting the container first, and then deleting the volume.
In your case, delete the volume named `pgadmin`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Additional to all the solutions above, make sure that **Postgres is not running on the local machine out of Docker** because it might conflict with the Postgres instance in Docker